# Laravel 5.1 routes not working except for index

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have an old Laravel 5.1 app that a prior webmaster created, that I am now responsible for maintaining. I am trying to get the app loading correctly on my local machine. Using homestead/vagrant for that.

I am getting the following error whenever I try to navigate to one of the routes in the app

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
  return View::make('index');
});

Route::get('config', 'ConfigController@generate');

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function() {
  Route::resource('groups', 'GroupController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
  Route::resource('/resources', 'ResourceController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
  Route::resource('ips', 'IpController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
  Route::resource('options', 'OptionController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
  Route::resource('hosts', 'HostController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));
  Route::resource('config', 'ConfigController', array('only' => array('show', 'update')));
  Route::get('/deploy', 'ConfigController@deploy');
});
```

The index route works but does not load fully load the front page. As you can tell from the image below
[image]

I'm not sure what is going on with this as I have never used route groups before. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can provide more details upon request.

Note: The application uses server side LDAP authentication to access the page. Not sure if that would be causing the issue or not.

Apache:

```
Alias /ezproxy-config "/opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/sites/staff2.library.ohio.edu/apps/app-ezproxy-config/current/public/"
  <Directory /opt/rh/httpd24/root/var/www/sites/staff2.library.ohio.edu/apps/app-ezproxy-config/current/public/>
    AllowOverride All
    Include conf.d/vhosts.d/includes/h5bp.conf

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Library Web Services Staff - Enter OHIO ID and Password"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap

    AuthLDAPBindDN "LIB-LDAPsvc@ohio.edu"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword Drtbovr_Svvy

    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ad.ohio.edu:389/OU=People,DC=Ohio,DC=Edu?cn,displayname,department,mail

    <RequireAny>
       Require ldap-group CN=Lib_Dept_IT,OU=Departments,OU=Groups,OU=LIBRARY,OU=Ohio,DC=ohio,DC=edu
       Require ip 132.235.61.22
    </RequireAny>
  </Directory>
```

Comment: .htaccess all ok?

Comment: We don't use .htaccess for production/staging. And I don't believe there to be one for local development.

Comment: Check the public folder for the .htaccess and delete if it's in there. If not show us your apache conf file for that project (supposing you're using apache)

Comment: Deleted the .htaccess and still nothing. Adding apache conf to bottom of file

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: There error I am getting when trying to access one of the routes is 
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161: